# Yii 1, relational AR и named scopes

Tags: activerecord, yii, scope

Делаю простенькое приложение, надо вытащить страницу категории блога. Существуют две модели - Category и Post. У Post есть scope `paged`:

```
public function paged($page=1, $perPage=5)
{
    $this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
        'order' => 'created DESC',
        'limit' => $perPage,
        'offset' => ($page - 1) * $perPage,
    ));
    return $this;
}
```

Вытягиваю данные таким образом:

```
$category = Category::model()->with(array(
    'posts' => array(
        'scopes' => array('paged' => $page,),
    ),
    'postCount',
))->find('t.slug = :slug', array(':slug' => $slug));
```

Старый добрый `var_dump` в `paged()` подсказывает, что параметр приходит верно. Однако Yii всегда подтягивает последние посты (судя по всему, все), а лог запросов выводит следующее:

```
end:system.db.CDbCommand.query(
    SELECT "t"."id" AS "t0_c0", "t"."name" AS "t0_c1", "t"."slug" AS "t0_c2",
        "t"."post_count" AS "t0_c3", "posts"."id" AS "t1_c0",
        "posts"."category_id" AS "t1_c1", "posts"."user_id" AS "t1_c2",
        "posts"."name" AS "t1_c3", "posts"."slug" AS "t1_c4",
        "posts"."content" AS "t1_c5", "posts"."created" AS "t1_c6"
    FROM "categories" "t"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "posts" "posts" ON ("posts"."category_id"="t"."id")
    WHERE (t.slug = :slug) ORDER BY created DESC.
    Bound with :slug='category-1'
)
```

Т.е. никакой фильтрации записей не выполняется. ЧЯДНТ? Надо городить paged в категории вместо поста? Почему?

Comment: что то я не совсем понял, что вы хотите получить запросом?

Comment: @Ale_x конкретную страницу постов, принадлежащих выбранной категории.

Comment: то есть юзер на одной странице выбирает категорию - идет запрос на сервак - который в итоге  должен прислать страницу с постами данной категории?

Comment: @Ale_x Да. По факту я пытаюсь реализовать пагинацию.

Comment: @Ale_x, может хватит уже "если а, то б, а еще можно в"? У меня конкретный вопрос. Меня не интересуют пути обхода, я их знаю.

Answer (score 1):

так и работай тогда только с моделью Post - передавай в нее категорию и вытягивай запросом все посты.
Зачем те в запрос совать еще категории, если юзер те передал то, что он хочет посмотреть?
должно получится что то типа этого

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition='categoryID=:categoryID';
$criteria->params=array(':category'=>$categoryID);
$criteria->limit=$perPage;
$criteria->offset=($page - 1) * $perPage;
$post=Post::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

правим согласно комментарию что нада вывести инфу о категории

тогда в экшен добавь еще выборку категории как одной строки

```
$category=Category::model()->find('slug = :slug', array(':slug' => $slug));
```

потом получай ее ID и тащи в запрос к Postam и также передавай ее данные в представления.

Теперь почему не нада в твоем случае тащить все одним запросом.

вот смотри к примеру у тебя информация о категории тоже хранится не в 1-ой таблице, далее количество информации представим 20 полей.

Смотрим дальше модель Post содержит 10 полей. Если ты все вытянешгь одним запросом даже 5 постов - то у тя в каждой строке будет 20+10 =30 полей - причем 
20 полей постоянно будут дублироватся - для каждой строки.

Если делаем 2 запроса то данных тащим меньше да и соединений таблиц может быть гораздо меньше.

Вопрос зачем релейшены? вот если бы ты вытаскивал Первый 10 постов на странице - которые относятся к разным категориям - вот тут тебе и понадобятся они - потому как дублирования не будет (возможно и будет но не все)

Да и в твоем случае опять же неправильно сделано, так как в твоем запросе ОСНОВНОЕ это POST - вот к нему и нада приделывать релейшен - тогда и пагинация отработает верно

Comment: > так и работай тогда только с моделью Post 

Конкретно в данной ситуации надо вывести, как минимум, некоторую информацию о категории, и ищется она по slug, поэтому напрямую материализовать айдишник не получится. Да и возникает вопрос зачем вообще тогда relational active record.

Comment: @Ale_x

> Теперь почему не нада в твоем случае тащить все одним запросом. ...
> причем 20 полей постоянно будут дублироватся - для каждой строки.

См. приведенный запрос. Ничего там не дублируется, он не через джойн идет. При более глубоких связях и through возможно и будут джойны, но у меня их нет сейчас.

> Да и в твоем случае опять же неправильно сделано, так как в твоем запросе ОСНОВНОЕ это POST

Никак нет.

> [примеры]

В результате все связки, которые я пытаюсь запрятать в модель, вылезают наружу. Я умею так писать, честно, только я хочу все сделать через AR.

Comment: вот это все 
"t"."id" AS "t0_c0", "t"."name" AS "t0_c1", "t"."slug" AS "t0_c2","t"."post_count" AS "t0_c3"

относится к инфе о категории - и в каждой результирующей строке которые вернет MySQL -данные будут одинаковы для постов одной категории

И почему это "основная" модель  у тебя не POST??- объясни

Comment: Хм, с запросом что-то совсем пропил память.  

> И почему это "основная" модель у тебя не POST??- объясни

Потому что основная модель - категория.

Comment: вот твой же комментарий  @Ale_x конкретную страницу постов, принадлежащих выбранной категории.

Подлежащие в этом предложение  какое слово??

Вот если бы ты на странице выводил все Категории с выводом 5 последних постов (Дерево) - то да основная модель у тя была бы Категория

Comment: @Ale_x, если будет удобней, представь вместо категории с постами пост с комментариями.

Comment: да никакой разницы))
А вот с таким подходом как у тебя - нада достать 10 последних комментов к 5 последним постам определенной категории) - с чего начнешь ? что тут основная модель?

почитай еще раз http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/database.arr  -там прямо твой пример описан - и там тоже идут от Post а не от Categors